# Can I reset breakers from my computer with the Schneider Smart Panel?

Tags: smart-home

I've been looking into [Schneider smart panels](http://www.schneider-electric.com/b2b/en/products/product-launch/smart-panels/overview.jsp) recently for home monitoring.  From what I'm reading, it appears that they have the ability to monitor your home's electric usage on all the various circuits real time.  They are connected by Ethernet (not wireless, unfortunately), so it appears that I will be able to see statistics from my home computer.

One thing, however, remains unclear to me: Are you able to reset a circuit when it blows from your computer, or will I have to trek down to the utility room every time I accidentally plug two toasters into the same circuit?

Comment: If you really are in the habit of connecting two toasters to the same circuit, you should investigate other methods of making this less likely (like placing low drain loads in specific sockets, or changing the tabletop layout). Just to reduce the chance of multiple failures ocuring together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you would not be able to reset a breaker.  Their "smarts" are for monitoring the panels and breakers, not operating them.

It would be a huge safety issue if homeowners could remotely reset breakers.  Breakers pop for a reason - there's an unsafe condition nearby. But if you could reset the breaker from anywhere on the globe, you would have no idea if the problem's been fixed or not, and energizing the circuit could start a fire.  Or consider that someone local may already be trying to fix the circuit that popped, and you remotely energized it while they're working on it.

Breakers on transmission lines are different, because they're repaired and operated by trained engineers who follow strict safety protocols.  But home and commercial equipment has to be as safe as possible by default.